# R plyr applied on row

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I have a data frame like this:

```
    mat.in=data.frame(site=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
    var=c('product.A','product.B','energy','product.A','product.B','energy'),
    year.2011=c(12,10,40,14,12,60),year.2012=c(13,11,45,25,13,65))
```

For every 'site' I want to divide by 'energy' [numcol wise], so I would get:

```
    mat.out=data.frame(site=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
    var=c('product.A','product.B','energy','product.A','product.B','energy'),
    year.2011=c(12,10,40,14,12,60),year.2012=c(13,11,45,25,13,65),
    quot.2011=c(0.30,0.25,1.00,0.23,0.20,1.00),quot.2012=c(0.29,0.24,1.00,0.38,0.20,1.00))
```

This would be ideally suited for ddply from the package plyr in combination with numcolwise of that package. 
But somehow I can't get it right - the problem is to pick out the 'energy' component.

Anybody knows how to solve this? [thanks in advance...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job in your example:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mat.in, .(site), transform, quote.2011 = year.2011/year.2011[var=="energy"],      
      quote.2012 = year.2012/year.2012[var=="energy"])
```

To do this more generally, I would first `melt` the data to turn year into a value not a column name.

Here's how it would work with a `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
mat.m <- melt(mat.in, id.vars=1:2, variable.name="year")
mat.m$year <- sub("year.", "", mat.m$year)
mat.out <- ddply(mat.m, .(site, year), transform, quote = value/value[var=="energy"])
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, it works! I have tried it also with your melt suggestion, but get 'non-numeric argument to binary operator'.

Answer (score 5):

Cool answer from @seancarmody.

Here is another way to do it using base functions:

```
# Select and join frames
mat.out<-merge(mat.in[grep("product", mat.in$var),], mat2 <- mat.in[mat.in$var=="energy",], "site")
# Calculate the quot values
mat.out$quot.2011=mat.out$year.2011.x/mat.out$year.2011.y
mat.out$quot.2012=mat.out$year.2012.x/mat.out$year.2012.y

# And if needs be you can remove the energy columns
mat.out[,-c(5,6,7)]
```

And here is a way to do it using `sqldf`:

```
variable<-'p.site,p.var,p.year_2011,p.year_2012,
           p.year_2011/e.year_2011 AS quot_2011,
           p.year_2012/e.year_2012 AS quot_2012'
tables<- '(SELECT *
           FROM    `mat.in`
           WHERE   var LIKE \"product%\"
           )
           AS p,
           (SELECT *
           FROM    `mat.in`
           WHERE   var LIKE \"energy\"
           )
           AS e'

fn$sqldf("SELECT $variable FROM $tables WHERE  p.site=e.site")
```

And here is a way using `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(mat.in, key="site")
# Join
mat.out <- dt[var %like% "product"][dt[var=="energy"]]
# Calculate
mat.out <- mat.out[,quot.2011:=year.2011/year.2011.1]
mat.out <- mat.out[,quot.2012:=year.2012/year.2012.1]
```

---

Edit from Matthew :

Building on that, a slightly more advanced (and faster) `data.table` way, using *join inherited scope* :

```
dt <- data.table(mat.in, key="site")
dt[dt[var=="energy"],quot.2011:=year.2011/i.year.2011]
dt[dt[var=="energy"],quot.2012:=year.2012/i.year.2012]
```

Notice the `i.` prefix which tells it to get that variable from `i` rather than `x`. Similar to SQL table name prefixes.  This avoids the large `merge` step; the technique described in FAQ 1.12.

When multiple `:=` in `j` is implemented, that'll become :

```
dt <- data.table(mat.in, key="site")
dt[dt[var=="energy"], { quot.2011:=year.2011/i.year.2011
                        quot.2012:=year.2012/i.year.2012 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks Sean & ROLO. I can't get the melt version working [Error in var == "energy" :  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types" but the first option works.

Comment: Are you using `reshape2`? Which version of R? I just tried the code again and got no errors.

Comment: Hi Sean and ROLO - my fault; it works on the code on this page, but not on my [much larger] dataset. Can't find what it is. I followed the steps carefully, checked with str(mydata) etc.

Comment: Maybe wrong values in the var column? What do `summary(mat.in$var)` and `class(mat.in$var)`on the larger table tell you?

Comment: Hi Rolo, summary(mat.in$var gives: Length     Class      Mode 
   211806 character character. class mat.in$var gives 'character'. I noticed that the nr of values per 'year' is not the same, e.g. 2008 = 264709 and 2009 = 264701, could that be the reason? Using R 2.14 64 bit on #! Linux, reshape2.

Comment: That could be a problem, but perhaps you already found that out in the meantime. You could also take a look at the `all=TRUE` parameter of merge to obtain a 'full join'.

Answer (score 0):

Just using base functions:

```
mat.r <- reshape(mat.in, direction="long", varying=3:4)
 # Could not figure out how to get the divisor "lined up" unless db-normalized
matd <- as.data.frame(lapply( split(mat.r, list(mat.r[,1], mat.r[,3]) ), 
                              FUN=function(x) x$year/x$year[x$var=="energy"]) )

#----------------
matd
  A.2011    B.2011    A.2012    B.2012
1   0.30 0.2333333 0.2888889 0.3846154
2   0.25 0.2000000 0.2444444 0.2000000
3   1.00 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000

 reshape(matd, direction="long", varying=list(1:2, 3:4))[2:3]
       A.2011    A.2012
1.1 0.3000000 0.2888889
2.1 0.2500000 0.2444444
3.1 1.0000000 1.0000000
1.2 0.2333333 0.3846154
2.2 0.2000000 0.2000000
3.2 1.0000000 1.0000000

 mat.out <- cbind(mat.in, reshape(matd, direction="long", varying=list(1:2, 3:4))[2:3])
 mat.out
 #------------------    
    site       var year.2011 year.2012    A.2011    A.2012
1.1    A product.A        12        13 0.3000000 0.2888889
2.1    A product.B        10        11 0.2500000 0.2444444
3.1    A    energy        40        45 1.0000000 1.0000000
1.2    B product.A        14        25 0.2333333 0.3846154
2.2    B product.B        12        13 0.2000000 0.2000000
3.2    B    energy        60        65 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks DWin. The only solution missing is now via the [fast] data.table package.

Comment: Added data.table (though not necessarily the most optimal way of using it).